# Dynamically Loading a component which has Router Setup?

Tags: angular

I am having a login component which loads at the beginning.After user clicks on login button i am dynamically adding component which has route config and router-links...I can see my router-links but when i click on them i cant see any content in router-outlet Here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KzCNxEthu6dRiGeSGToe?p=preview

```
    UserLogin() {
    this.DCLloader.loadAsRoot(AppComponent, '#login', this.injector);
}
```

This is how i am adding the component.My question is can i add a component which has router links dynamically? If yes, why is my demo not working? How can i correct this mistake?Somebody please help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like support for this was added recently:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7365
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7318

This already landed in beta.9
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta9-2016-03-09

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you try to achieve, but if the purpose is to redirect after a successfull login, see this example:

https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac/blob/angular2/src/main/webapp/app/app.component.ts

The idea is to set the login page as the default one in the `@RouteConfig`. 
When the login is successful you redirect to a given page (/user for example). 
Then you have to check every time a page changes that the user is still logged and redict to the login page if he's not.

Comment: the type which you mentioned can be done easily...But when an user is logged in based upon his permission i will load only those components which he can access.In that condition i dont want to import all components

Comment: I understand, we use a directive to solve this problem. It removes the component if the user is not authorized to see it. https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac/blob/angular2/src/main/webapp/app/utils/is-authorized.directive.ts